# Are questions that can be answered right only negatively welcomed

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Hoping that my problem will be solved, I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737776/how-to-color-specific-word-in-a-container-using-css). My question attracted many useless answers at the beginning from users that probably didn't read my question till end. If anyone can reword it the better way, I appreciate it.
In 2 days I considered to start a bounty. A little later I understood that there is no answer that will suit me 100%, however some good answers were provided.
So recently I got two downvotes, maybe because of misunderstanding my question, maybe because only 100% correct answer is "No". I don't know the reason of down votes.
 Maybe I am misunderstanding some rules that know old, trusted users - because a [130k+ user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263525/dystroy) left a comment about down voting my question.

This made me ask a question  - would you ask a question if you don't know definitely that it can only be answered negatively?

Comment: @Bart See his answer before edit. I simply rephrased his comment. And I didn't down vote anyone for misunderstanding me.

Comment: That doesn't improve your comment.

Comment: Your question about CSS was legit and in scope of StackOverflow. You didn't know at this time it was impossible (I don't think agrm's answer is actually better than just adding a <span>). So you have rights to ask this question, and if the answer is just "No it's not possible", you should accept it and then it closes it. I once answered a question from somebody asking "Can I do.." and the answer was "nope".

Answer (score 3):

> would you ask a question if you don't know definitely that it can only be answered negatively?

I would ask questions I don't know the answer to and which fit in the scope of the site. That the ultimate answer might be "you fundamentally can't achieve what you want" doesn't really matter. It could be a valid answer and doesn't invalidate the question per se.