# Is "this is not possible" an acceptable answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

There are many "how do I do X" questions in Stack Overflow. I'm not counting questions with no merit ("do this for me"), but actual, useful questions that show research by the poster.

When the answer is "this is not possible, because of so and so", should that be an answer or rather a comment? Is there a general rule, or does it rather depend on how complex it is to reach that conclusion?

This [bounty question for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006749/android-how-to-figure-out-if-email-was-sent-by-checking-sent-items) is an example of what I mean (especially since the bounty *explicitly* asks for a working solution).

Comment: If it's not possible, then it's not possible, and that is a valid answer. Here is [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4907854/456814).

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer

Comment: @apaul34208 very distantly related, if at all. "Don't do it" is a very different answer from "It can't be done". The first is a recommendation, the second is a fact.

Comment: [It seems to be allowed by the community.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722926/can-php-be-used-without-the-sigil-for-variables/722936#722936)

Comment: Anything is possible in computing, given enough time and money.  Whether it can be done in a practical way is another matter.

Comment: @Robert Harvey In that case, can you tell me how to find the solution to the equation x = k / n where n is 0? A Python implementation would be best.

Comment: if (n == 0) return 0;

Comment: Most of the times these questions are XY problems. I generally do answer saying that it isn't possible (and why is that) *and* providing a solution to the actual problem (and not to fixing the solution the OP wanted).

Comment: It is an awful question.  The pattern "can I solve X by doing Y?" is very unconstructive and nobody ever thinks that "no" is a useful answer.  Just ask "How do I do X?"

Comment: @HansPassant I agree wholeheartedly. Funny thing is, he ended up doing what I suggested in the comment, then awarded the bounty to someone else. :-/

Comment: Related: [Close reason for "not in my universe" questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258731) Sort of related: [What to do with plain wrong questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260496)

Comment: They said the same thing about flying.

Comment: But this is unfair! I asked the same question and got down voted! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256443/are-questions-that-can-be-answered-right-only-negatively-welcomed

Comment: "not an answer" - damryfbfnetsi *some time ago*     declined - Answers of the type "this is not possible, and here's why" are actual answers.

Comment: I cast such a flag a while ago, and it was declined with that reason by a moderator

Comment: I don't think so, in the past those kind of answers given by me were either deleted or converted to a comment. As such I never post this as an answer and its wasted time and effort. Never getting an answer is probably enough to say "its not possible" for SO. After all when asking "how to do X" saying "its not possible" is not exactly answering, so the question is unanswerable.

Comment: This applies also to questions of the form "What is the good justification for this decision regarding a language feature?" for which the terse and boring "This is the rule, period." is often downvoted or even DELETED.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you can *actually* demonstrate that something is *impossible* (as opposed to simply not knowing how to do it), then go ahead and post it as an answer. Doing things this way

1. Lets you provide proof of your claim (such as a quote from spec or documentation explicitly stating that what the asker wants is not allowed), or at least a thorough description of what you consider to be all the possible ways to approach the problem and why they all fail.
2. Exposes your claim to voting, letting future visitors see whether the community agrees with it.

This is surely better than making a claim with no or minimal substantiation in a comment where voting can't be used to express disagreement and the details of the claim cannot be argued over and amended.

Consider [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804576/is-there-any-way-to-remove-photo-tags-with-facebook-api/17381078#17381078) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059497/1709587) of mine which claim (at great length) that what the question asker is requesting is impossible. It would plainly not have been more helpful for either the question asker or future visitors if I had only posted a short comment simply stating that the task was impossible without justification - why would anyone believe me if I won't show my working? An answer is often the only tool that gives you enough space to demonstrate that something cannot be done and thus prevent the question asker, or future visitors, from pointlessly reproducing your work pursuing the impossible.

Remaining silent for the sake of some vague idea that these aren't "answers" would probably have wasted dozens of man-hours of people futilely performing exactly the same tests as me, and helped nobody.

Comment: If the question is if a freezer can heat then you have a hard time to show why it can't. Often the effort is not worth the question.

Comment: @MikeLischke - a freezer can heat: set it really cold, turn the freezer around, crack an egg over the condensor or engine.

Comment: @MikeLischke If the question is being asked out of curiosity about the workings of a freezer, then Erno's answer is indeed the correct one (and nobody who doesn't understand a freezer well enough to know it shouldn't answer). On the other hand, if the question is being asked because the asker *wants to heat something* and has assumed that a he needs a freezer to achieve this, then the right response is "A freezer isn't the right tool for the job; freezers are designed for cooling things. You should use an oven or a radiator instead." Whether it's actually possible with a freezer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 24):

I have generally been inclined to comment rather than answer when something is impossible, because *someone else might be smarter than me*.

Just because it doesn't appear possible in the frame through which I have viewed or the circumstances through which the OP arrived at it, someone else may be able to approach the solution from an angle neither I nor the OP could have envisioned.  At the very least, that would invalidate my "sorry, not possible" answer and make it wrong.

So my comment usually goes something like:

> *I don't believe this is possible, as far as my experience can gauge. Hopefully someone else can prove me wrong and provide a good solution.*

For people who pay attention to whether questions already have answers or not before clicking through to attempt their own answers, a question with zero answers on the homepage may end up receiving more traffic - which makes it more likely the OP will get that "outside the box" answer from somebody clever (featured bounty questions may feel less of this effect).

Comment: I agree with this. However (and this may sound selfish and garner me ill-will :)) I've seen this happen with 2 or 3 bounty questions recently: various comments say "this is not possible", then someone comes in and answers "this is not possible" (without expanding much on the topic), and gets the bounty. It doesn't _feel_ right, but there's nothing explicit saying it's wrong either.

Comment: +1. What typically happens when someone says "No, this isn't possible" is that several other posters add answers that show that it *is* indeed possible, and then the "not possible" answer gets downvoted heavily because it's been clearly proven to be incorrect.

Comment: @matiash Yeah that will happen, and I would say that's more the OP's problem than yours for not waiting on the best possible answer, though it may sting to miss out on a +100 bounty.  If it doesn't feel right to you, then that's maybe a good enough reason not to collect that bounty for yourself.

Comment: I'm in partial agreement. A lot of times, things are "really" possible, if for no reason other than the fact that languages are generally Turing Complete. However, if you're really an expert you can usually give a pretty nuanced answer on the order of "this is not impossible, but may as well be; I mean, unless you want to write a tool to inspect your program in memory and...".

Comment: This. Also, *what is not possible today may be possible in the future*.

Comment: I've said something is impossible before, left it as an answer, and been proven wrong by somebody smarter than me. No shame in that I think. And if my answer imparts useful information to the context of the page I'll leave it up, even if it starts to collect downvotes.

Answer (score 20):

#### Treat an answer of "no" exactly the same as an answer of "yes".

If you want to say "no" to an answer, and you are as confident as you would hold yourself to when answering "yes", answer. These ideals of holding back answers until they are perfect strike for an often-unattainable goal.

I occasionally write answers going "To the best of my knowledge, you can do ... to solve this." If you allow uncertainty in that direction, you should allow uncertainty in the other.

If you end up being wrong or the API changes, you're allowed to withdraw the answer. If it's superseded by a better answer, you're allowed to withdraw your answer. If there's a slim chance you were wrong when you posted it, downvotes or people's comments will alert you.

**TL;DR: There are mechanisms in place to deal with people being wrong. Don't get panicked about it.**

Comment: This is absolutely correct, and covers the flaw in [Mehrdad's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261186/): whether the answer is "yes" or "no" -- or "no, but..." -- you should _back your answer up_.

Comment: I also agree with this, and it addresses a point that I felt significant but didn't manage to get into my answer - that "you might be wrong" and "the answer might become obsolete" are points usually true of *any* answer you can give, positive or negative. It seems perverse to use it as an argument against negative answers only.

Answer (score 5):

## Simply put, yes!

As long as you really believe it's impossible, then **please do everyone a favor and answer as such**.
Furthermore, [if there isn't an alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24074756/541686) (unlike in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18053186/541686) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14169897/541686) question) that you think the OP would/should be interested in, then *just say "no, it's impossible" and get it over with.

I have done this on multiple occasions ([here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839611/541686)), and people have done this to me as well, *which I have always appreciated*. And [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9981012/541686) one instance in which no one had the heart to say it's impossible, even though it seems to be, which was clearly unhelpful. I would much rather have been told "this is impossible".

Whatever you do, ***please* don't add fluff** just to make it more than 1 line.  There is **nothing** inherently wrong with a [1-line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17387615/541686) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6811036/541686).  People need to stop downvoting them, and you can help by encouraging succinctness.

Comment: I disagree. A lot of people believe that *what they don't know* is *impossible*. That annoys me to no end -- I tend to ask difficult questions and getting "you can't do that" answers when I *know* it's possible, but I don't know exactly how, is very, very annoying to me.

Comment: @Sklivvz: That's why I said **"as long as you really believe it's impossible"** and not "as long as you're guessing it's impossible".

Comment: @Sklivvz: When someone asks "is there an API for doing X?" there is literally no way to *prove* nonexistence other than listing every single API in the framework. Yet someone who's an expert in the framework might already know very well that the API doesn't exist, because they know the framework inside and out. What exactly is wrong with them saying so?

Comment: That should be "as long as you can _prove_ it's impossible": the answer should contain such a proof (just like an answer that says the opposite should contain working code)

Comment: @Sklivvz: Sorry, just posted another comment, see the second one above.

Comment: Saw that -- that's not an "impossible" answer, it's a "no" answer to a yes/no question: I believe we are *literally* talking past each other :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz: Er... then what exactly is an impossible answer?

Comment: e.g. "Can you call C++ code from C#?" "It's impossible"

Comment: @Sklivvz: I don't get it, isn't the answer to that either "yes" or "no"??

Comment: Let's move to [chat]. You are right, though, that's a bad example.

Comment: @Sklivvz: "Moving the discussion to chat failed" :(

Comment: @Sklivvz: Continuing here... honestly, there's no such thing as an "impossible" answer that isn't a yes/no answer; every question that invites such an answer is of the form "is X possible?" (or "how can I do X?", etc.) to which the answer is clearly either yes ("yes, it's possible, this is how...") or no ("no, it's impossible, [here are some alternatives if they exist]"). There's literally no distinction whatsoever.

Comment: The correct example I meant: "How do you call C++ code from C#?" -- It's either possible or not, but unless one can prove it's impossible one should simply comment that maybe the question should be changed to whether it *is* possible. However, that's really up to the OP: in fact, it is easy to prove that it's possible to call C++ code from C# even without knowing how (e.g. by noticing that windows API are eventually somehow called from C#). What I would like to avoid is people answering with "It's impossible" when it's not even a proper answer just because they believe so.

Comment: @Sklivvz: What would you expect a "proof" of that to look like?

Comment: E.g. a link to a MSDN page that says so? An explanation why it is not possible in their opinion? "You can't call Java code directly from Perl because Java runs inside a virtual machine, and Perl doesn't"

Comment: @Sklivvz: Er... there isn't an MSDN page for everything that's impossible, and the "explanation" for something being impossible is simply that "the necessary means do not exist". You can't expect anything reasonable in so many cases. Like, imagine if someone asked, "how can I emit my own Javascript bytecode?" I don't think you'll find any documentation saying this is impossible; the answer is simply that *it isn't possible*. There isn't any "opinion" here, it's simply a fact that the APIs don't exist, but the only "proof" is to *list all JS APIs* and show none of them has that functionality.

Comment: I still believe that "To my knowledge, it's impossible" is a bad, bad answer. It doesn't explain anything at all.

Comment: @Sklivvz: Sorry if this sounds annoying, but your very comment here was a bad, bad comment. It simply ignored my logic and reasserted what you believe without explaining how you think my reasoning or example should be corrected.

Comment: I am asserting that it should not be posted. I suggested ways, but your answer was "they don't always apply". True -- in which case, it's not appropriate to answer at all.

Comment: @Sklivvz: Er... so you think the example question I posed should remain unanswered indefinitely?

Comment: I did not say that: the fact that one user can't come up with a convincing, insightful and informative answer does not prevent others from doing so. The problem is that a lot of users are *convinced* that there is no answer besides what you say... a part from the ones who actually can answer in some way. We don't want the firsts to answer with bad answers. That's noise.

Comment: @Sklivvz: Er... *all* I'm trying to ask is *what do you think the appropriate way to answer my sample question is?* You seem to be saying there is no answer while you're also saying it shouldn't remain unanswered. In your *perfect* world, what would be the response to that question?

Comment: It's actually possible... https://code.google.com/p/moe-js/source/browse/tracing/engine/bytecode-builder.js?spec=svn3e38c98b14e835c9487983c12ec351de163adb30&r=3e38c98b14e835c9487983c12ec351de163adb30

Comment: @Sklivvz: Sigh. What if it wasn't implemented? Then what would your answer be?

Comment: How can I answer this? You are presenting me with an impossible question! I would not answer a question I do not know the answer to. If I *know* that something is impossible, then I always *know* the reason why. If I merely *suspect* something is impossible, then I don't answer. This is exactly the same if i *know* or *suspect* something is possible.

Comment: @Sklivvz: That file you linked me to seems to have been written in 2012. Is it *really that hard* for you to just imagine going back to 2011 and answering the question I posed to you in that context??

Comment: Let's agree to limit ourselves to concrete examples instead of imaginary ones. Also, what *I* would do is irrelevant. We are discussing rules for the community, which is made of different people. The assumption is that if I don't know an answer, then someone else does -- not that I should answer "impossible". Yes, some questions will be (and are!) without answer -- I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: @Sklivvz: You're dodging my question. You should also read the second part of this comment, and I have nothing more to say beyond this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript/4907854#comment30496784_4907854

Comment: Hang on; why shouldn't I add fluff in order to make my answer more than one line?  People routinely flag one-line answers as "this is a comment, not an answer" because, even though they're only one line long, they can't be bothered to read it.

Comment: @tmyklebu: To teach people to stop knee-jerk flagging/downvoting.

Comment: Does that work at all?  It doesn't seem like *anybody* in the process---either flaggers or mods---bothers to give anything more than a cursory glance.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Very true...

Answer (score 5):

I do sometimes answer these questions. Here are points that make me inclined to answer:

1. I'm a domain expert.
2. There's a fundamental reason the OPs idea is not possible and I can explain that reasoning.

Also, my reputation gives a certain authority to my answer. Being told that something is impossible is sometimes not credible alone. On the other hand if an experienced user is saying the same thing there's a lot more evidence that his statement is true.

Answer (score 3):

Reference: [How do I export the components of an app in Lotus Domino Designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014290/how-do-i-export-the-components-of-an-app-in-lotus-domino-designer/24046481#24046481) for an instance where I provided a solution to a question that a domain expert (Torsten Link) said was impossible.

I think that answering "it's not possible" is acceptable, as long as you recognize that someone might be able to approach the problem in a manner that you didn't expect.  That's one of the reasons why StackExchange lets more than one person answer a question, after all -- this isn't a site where one person gets all the credit, this is a site where any helpful answer can get credit.

I like Mark Amery's idea, "explain why it's impossible".  Someone may see through the thicket in a way that you cannot, and that way we all benefit.