# Failed audit - no explanation was given though

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Audit in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5509353

I've read this on Meta: [Is "this is not possible" an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer)

And I disagree with the result of the audit because it does *not* look OK. Even though "not possible" is an acceptable answer, there should be some explanation on *why* it is not possible.

I know that **wrong answers should not be deleted**, however this answer is not only arguably wrong, but low-quality as it does not provide any explanation. Either way, it does not seem to be a good audit answer.

Comment: I would argue that's not an answer at all. It's a jokey comment about why he shouldn't bother trying, and doesn't attempt to answer the question whatsoever.

Comment: @animuson Is there a way for a moderator to override/revoke the review ban or do I have to wait 30 days?

Comment: I can lift it for you, but if you fail another review audit any time soon it'll automatically trigger another 30-day review ban.

Answer (score 11):

You're right. That is not an answer.

The posts that show up as audits are automatically generated by a computer program, so there will be errors like this.

---

*I would personally find it really hard to delete an answer with that high a score. And probably only a mod could with that high of a score. But technically, it should be deleted.*

Answer (score 3):

Correction to iStimple's answer: audits are automatically generated by a **dumb** computer program. The problem is that it can grab any post that was deleted by a diamond mod and base the audit on that. And diamond mods have ways of seeing the greater picture that we normal users lack.

The delete and therefore the review audit could thus be completely unrelated to any actual problems with the post. It could have been deleted because of something that a normal user cannot easily spot, such as spam in disguise, copy/paste plagiarism, use of bots to post the answer etc etc.

Particularly the first post and low-quality post reviews get a lot of really strange review audits because of this. So I wouldn't advise anyone to do those two categories of edit reviews: there is a big chance of getting a review ban because the SO review-audit-generating algorithm for these categories is just too dumb.

If you do first post or low-quality reviews, you have to be very careful and learn how to dodge the system, by going to the original post and check if the answer was deleted by a diamond mod. Otherwise you might suddenly find yourself banned, out of the blue.

Comment: @iStimple Be that as it may, the above still holds true. Posts deleted by diamond mods for whatever reason end up in the review audit system, which in turn can generate very strange audits.

Comment: @Lundin In that case, how is anything in your answer relevant to the question, if it isn't what happened here?

Comment: @hvd It is highly relevant to the topic of "why are some review audits broken", which is what the question is about.