# A valid answer ended up in the Low Quality queue and has probably been marked as not an answer

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, not-an-answer

This is my answer, now deleted, to [Text blurry after 3D transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176557/text-blurry-after-3d-transform/26241730#26241730)

> This is just the way transforms and all the similar effects are implemented. Don't try fixing your code, just wait for browser vendors to do something about this issue or don't use these techniques if that blurriness bothers you.

In my opinion, this answers the question, but seeing the automated review queue comment I assume some people don't agree. Can somebody tell me why is this answer not an answer?

Comment: Here are the review links: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5942789 http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5942798

Comment: That's not an answer, and it would be a shame if you were awarded a bounty for it.  Both answers should be deleted until someone has an actual solution, if one exists.  It would be nice of you to delete it and leave your comment as a comment.

Comment: I think the guidelines at [Is "this is not possible" an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261168) are useful here (see also [Is "don't do it" a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891)). You can tell someone they're on the wrong track in an answer, as long as you **back it up**.

Comment: again the downvote brigade for someone using Meta as it's meant to be used

Comment: @Will Think about the problem stated in the question for a bit, and you'll come to realize that DJDavid98's answer does in fact state the reality of the situation - what the asker is trying to do with their ugly-angle image transform **should not be expected to work well**, at least not for fine text.

Comment: @ChrisStratton again, you can do that in a comment, without attempting to take a bounty for an "answer" that doesn't provide a solution to the OP's issue.  It's a dick move.  Compare it with the other (new) answers that provide actual workarounds.

Comment: @will - it's an answer as its an "ending" not a comment as a suggested direction.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Well, that's a load of crap.  Let's just disagree and leave the poor OP here and his inbox alone.

Comment: eddie_cat, "the way Meta is meant to be used" includes doing a modicum of homework even if you have a simple [support] question. This post does not show any effort at understanding the situation; it may be that some downvoters therefore thought it was a poor contribution to Meta. It may be that some of them thought that the answer was also self-evident, and thus that this was a not a good use of time. (Note that I myself may have not downvoted, upvoted, or voted at all here.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell what more could OP have said? He thought it answered the question and wanted to know why other people might be disagreeing. What should he have searched for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer isn't "not an answer", and doesn't meet the criteria for deletion in the LQP queue.  Some people feel that it fails to answer the question, or that it isn't a quality answer to the question.  They are more than welcome to express that view through downvotes on the post.

It is a common misconception of users that "not an answer" is an appropriate flag for an answer that fails to answer a question, when in fact it is for an answer that *doesn't even try* to answer the question, such as answers that just as a new question, ask clarifying questions, etc, which clearly is not the case here.  However, while the post was mistakenly flagged, no action was taken on that flag, so there is no issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure that it actually answers the question. Maybe you don't know of a way, maybe there isn't. Overall, I don't see your answer as useful even with my limited knowledge of the technologies involved and some quick google search. Saying

> Don't try fixing your code, just wait for browser vendors to do something about this issue or don't use these techniques if that blurriness bothers you.

isn't quite helpful. If you had actually provided another way to get the same effect, I doubt any close votes would have been raised.

Had I seen this in the review queue, I would have skipped it after looking at the question but at first glance, it doesn't look like your answer provide one to the question. I understand why some people might be flagging to delete your answer.

Josh Caswell provides some [good](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261168/773623) [links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer) as to why some people might be flagging to delete your answer.

Comment: The fact that an answer fails to adequately answer the question doesn't make it NAA though.  This post clearly doesn't meet the criteria for deletion from the LQP queue and should be left alone.  If you feel that the post fails to answer the question then you should downvote it.  If you're evaluating a post's technical merit from the LQP queue then you're doing it wrong, as that's not what it's there for.

Comment: @Servy The way it is worded right now, I can understand some people casting close vote on it. It could be worded to be more clear that it is not possible and provide the why of it.

Comment: That may well improve the quality of the answer and change it from one that is worth downvoting to one that is worth upvoting.  It has not bearing on whether it's an answer or not.  With or without that it still very clearly should not be deleted from the LQP queue.  The assertion that it *is* appropriate to delete it without such an edit is wrong.

Answer (score -4):

Your answer is perfectly fine. I don't think an answer has to solve a problem if it provides a reasonable explanation for the behavior.

In cases like these flagging your answer for moderator attention can be useful if you want an expert to have a look at it.

Also, be sure that in the length of time, people will upvote your answer if it's useful for them or if they think it's actually constructive.

Comment: The down vote on the other answer is mine, because it's limited to Chrome only and it should have been a comment.

Comment: DJDavid : I think the other post is more of an answer than yours :) It's bad, but its some effort to provide a working code...

Comment: @EugenePodskal Yes, I know that because I wrote that second answer, I was only explaining that the rewiewer did not down-vote the other answer, I did.

Comment: In my opinion, it *would* be an answer if the poster added that the given code is chrome specific and that there's no reliable workaround for other browsers at this time, however, in the format it's currently in, it should be a comment.

Comment: If you remove the part that says the other guy is abusing the down-vote system and replace it with something like "misunderstood the review queue options" I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: Comments are not a ghetto for badly-written answers, @DJDavid98. If an answer lacks sufficient explanation (or is straight-up *wrong*), then downvote it (optionally, leave a comment explaining why it's wrong/unhelpful).

Comment: @Shog9 Can't downvote, my past upvote is now locked in.

Comment: I see no signs of voting abuse whatsoever.  Someone downvoting an answer that you like isn't abusing downvotes, he's simply someone who holds a different opinion of the quality of the post from you.  That's entirely fine.  A moderator isn't going to do anything about downvotes on a post just because you don't think that the post is bad.

Comment: If you happen to downvote 3 answers in once then it might be that you got off the wrong side of the bed in the morning. Also some people clearly think with reputation criteria.

Comment: If you down-vote three answers in a row it is possible that you have seen three bad answers.

Comment: Flagging is not useful here; moderators aren't going to review the technical content of your answer and give you a response. That's the role of other users (and they express the results of their reviews with up- and down-votes).

Comment: For your first sentence, I agree that an answer that proposes "this is not possible" or "you shouldn't do that" is fine, _provided that_ it justifies its stance.

Comment: Jay Blachard : who defines "bad answer" ? I would be rather careful on downvoting. Upvoting the best answer is sufficient to filter the rest. I'd only downvote if the answer is really mis-guiding .. or with unnecessary attitude / character (offensive)

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos You provided an incorrect answer that advocates the incorrect course of action and then are surprised when it gets downvoted?  The entire *purpose* of downvotes is to indicate that an answer is incorrect, or otherwise unhelpful.  If you're concerned about the amount of low quality content on the site then you should be concerned about the low quality content not getting enough downvotes, not about low quality content getting too many downvotes.  Down voting a low quality answer isn't bullying; it's providing helpful feedback on the quality of an answer.