# Why was my custom flag declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, specific-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095921/c-is-it-possible-to-pass-an-entire-enum-set-as-a-paramter-not-duplicate/13095953#13095953):

> No, this is not possible. What effect are you trying to achieve?

With the following custom reason:

> This answer, while just barely technically an answer, doesn't serve to add anything to the other answers to this question and can be safely deleted without harming anything.

I got this response:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

There are plenty of other, much more through answers. I don't have 20k rep, otherwise I would not have flagged and just voted to delete.

I have flagged many other similar answers of similar content, including several using that custom flag reason or similar, and gotten the answer deleted with a helpful flag.

Why was my flag declined, in this case?

Comment: Related: [Is “this is not possible” an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer)

Comment: Because *"flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"*, and bad answers can and should be dealt with by the community at large. Downvote, and consider flagging as Low Quality.

Comment: low quality / not an answer is the way (just the fact that the post ends with a question makes it look like a comment). Don't use too many custom flags, they're exhausting to process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I declined the flag.

You flagged a series of posts with that custom flag. While most of those were indeed valid, in this case there was no other answer that said 'Not possible'.

Answer (score 4):

Seeing the other answers you should have done the following:

- leave a comment *Yes, it is possible*,
- down vote,
- maybe flag as LQ
- move on

Although there is no harm in deleting it, there is also some value in keeping it around because it answers the question of the OP based on the false assumptions of the OP. Future visitors will probably find the question, some valuable and accepted answers and the answer that says: *Strictly speaking what you want can't be done*

Comment: If that custom flag got declined, a VLQ flag would also have been declined. Also, if there's value in keeping it, then by definition there is harm in deleting it.

Comment: @durron597 "*If that custom flag got declined, a VLQ flag would also have been declined*" Not necessarily. Your flag to a moderator was rejected because you shouldn't have flagged a moderator, as per the rejection message. So this has no bearing on whether the answer should or should not be deleted, *or* whether community would delete via LQP queue.

Comment: Maybe @durron597 that is true, but if a couple of users agree, which I think is possible for that answer, a VLQ would have worked. Lets not make this a game  of words but as the question has multiple answers, deleting this answer doesn't devaluate the question usefulness or its answers. It has value in the sense that it voices a different view ... as an answer it might not have helped much (which explains why it wasn t accepted) but is somewhat useful...