# What should I do with legitimate questions that can't be answered?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage, review-suspension

I'll just start off with what prompted me to post this.  I got a review suspension for [this triage review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27160810), which I marked as "Looks OK".  I know there are quite a lot of meta posts on "Why did I get a review suspension?" and I guess this post is no different, but I would like to focus more on how I should handle questions like this one in the future.  The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63886475/13623742), in a nutshell, is asking how to embed a webpage in an iframe such that the user cannot see what URL the content is coming from.  The question was closed as "Needs Details or Clarity".  What details or clarity do we expect from the OP in this case?  I'm pretty sure that was just used as a generic way to close the question, because it can't really be answered.  The answer is just plain "you can't".  [Someone even said it in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63886475/#comment112972209_63886475).  So what should I do in these cases, where the question itself is a perfectly valid, clear question, but cannot be answered?  Should I mark it as "Unsalvageable > Needs Details", or is my review suspension just an outlier, and I should continue marking questions like these as "Looks OK"?

---

**Edit:**

Somebody suggested [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261168/13623742) to me.  While that post is about answers, and my post is about questions, I think the two are related.  That post's [accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261184/13623742) suggests that answers that are simply "you can't" are perfectly fine answers.  My question is, can I apply that same logic to questions?  Are the questions that can only lead to those answers "Looks OK"?

Comment: @GinoMempin I think it's definitely related, but not a duplicate, since that post is about answers, not questions.  The link you provided suggests that there is nothing wrong with simple "you can't" answers.  I guess I'm asking if I can also apply that logic to questions, since I received a review suspension for doing so.

Comment: Aside, I find the _Triage_ queue really capricious. There are a lot of questions that seem like judgment calls to me, but end up in review suspensions. I’ve reviewed thousands of posts from other queues never received a suspension—but I reviewed 80 _Triage_ questions, and racked up something like five suspensions within a couple of weeks. Much of that is because I was new to reviewing and didn’t fully understand the criteria. But others seemed debatable, with questions on par with most posts on the site. Now I just avoid that queue and focus on _First Posts_ and _Low Quality_ instead.

Comment: Borderline illegal and unethical questions rarely fare well on SO. I'm pretty sure that the actual close reason for linked question is "I don't see any valid reasons to do so. Either come up with one of find properly shady place to ask".

Comment: To be clear, I’m not saying that my own suspensions were invalid. There just seem to be variables in the _Triage_ assessment that I’m not seeing. So I focus my time on areas where my effort provides more value to the community.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Is hiding a URL really illegal / unethical?  Not that I don't believe you, but could you provide a reputable source to back that claim?  What would the ethical implications be?  The OP of the question seems to be using it for online testing in a school environment.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong traditional use of "hide url"/"hide process" request is to write some tracking or otherwise questionable "tools". Like "you really don't need to know that my beautiful calendar control opens IFrame on hax0r.net just in case you type some passwords". Maybe you have decent number of good use cases - I don't - so really don't see myself voting to reopen such question.

Comment: *While this does not seem to apply to the specific question linked*, often enough the difference between "impossible" and "possible" is that the question *needs more detail* to clarify the constraints that make the problem solvable.

Comment: @JeremyCaney The review queues are a mess and Triage is a mess inside that mess. It's simply best to avoid it, because you're liable to just end creating more work for everyone: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real questions have answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)

Comment: Careful, @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica - that's probably considered unwelcoming nowadays. Honestly I'm surprised that Stack Exchange Inc. hasn't expunged those older blog posts yet.

Comment: @IanKemp: While I agree there are also issues with the some of the other review queues, those are different than _Triage_ and should be treated as such. For instance, I see answers in _Low Quality Posts_ deleted quite frequently which may be incorrect, but are actual attempted answers ([related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue). In those cases, I wish _more_ suspensions were handed out. My general critique is that the suspensions don’t seem to correlate to consistent criteria—but that goes in both directions.

Answer (score 37):

> So what should I do in these cases, where the question itself is a perfectly valid, clear question, but cannot be answered?

Very simple. Since “this is not possible” is an acceptable answer it can be answered. Post an answer if you feel the question is useful enough to warrant one. But don't forget to demonstrate that it isn't possible, as detailed in the already [linked answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261184/1536976) by Mark Amery.

Hint: I mentally auto-expand questions of type "How to do X?" into "Is it possible to do X and if so how to do it?". That helps.

A question with a negative answer can still be a useful question, especially if it's surprising that it isn't possible or if people often ask for that or if the reason why it's impossible delivers non-trivial insights.

Finally, things that are impossible now, can become possible in the future. A negative answer now can become superseded by a positive answer later. I've seen Q&A pairs where that happened.

Comment: I mentally answer questions of type "How do to X?" with the title of Zed Shaw's programming manifesto ("With Programming, m*******"). But I figure that wouldn't work as an actual answer, so I keep my mouth shut.

Comment: You can do more than mentally auto-expand; you can edit the question to actually say that... (not you @larsks ;-))

Comment: @HereticMonkey That would be a lot of work to rename all questions asking how to do something for relatively little gain while they would get considerably longer. More isn't always better. I would prefer to keep shorter titles and do the mental auto-expansion instead. It should be implied without needing to say it explicitly every time, or what do you think?

Comment: I was thinking that, if you're reading a question, and find yourself doing these kinds of mental gymnastics, why not help the next person/people out and edit the question so they don't have to do mental calisthenics? It would also help with premature closings as well, one would think, and teach the OP how to phrase their questions in a more explicit manner. "It should be implied" seems like thin ice when you're talking about people with the varying levels of English mastery we see on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes that would definitely be a possibility. But I don't see much advantage in longer question titles just to be on the safe side. I really think it should be just implied and understood without saying that questions asking to achieve something are also asking for the existence of a solution to their problems. I think it's relatively thick ice, but maybe not. We could ask the meta community if question of type "how to do..." should better more explicitly state the question for the existence of a solution.

Answer (score 9):

I think it got closed because of the follow up comment:

> ... I want something like Encrypting the iFrame from Server Side...

Use of the word “encrypting” may have confused things but there may also be confusion as to whether it is the shortened URL being exposed or the original one.

I think the use of the “needs clarity” close reason was sincere and the closure wasn’t about it not being possible.

Comment: Thank you for your insight.  I can see the possible confusion now, perhaps I was locking on to the wrong issue with the post, but I would think that would put it in the "Requires Editing" category, no?  Couldn't someone (not the author) just edit out the whole part about the URL shortener, as it is irrelevant, and then the question would be much clearer?  What makes this one "Needs Clarity" instead of "Requires Editing"?

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong "Requires Editing" doesn't mean what you think it means. It means that the question is already ontopic, just needs a bit of editing by anyone. If the author needs to clarify it, it's unsalvageable for the review, which means that only the author can potentially salvage it.

Comment: @Trilarion I understand that "Requires Editing" puts it in a Help & Improvement queue where someone else needs to edit the question; my question was "why couldn't they?"  I could see myself going in and removing everything about the URL shortener, I wouldn't need any input from the author to do that.  If you think that would help, I might still go do that.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong Sure, if you feel you can improve a question by editing, just do it.

Comment: *Couldn't someone (not the author) just edit out the whole part about the URL shortener, as it is irrelevant...* @CharlieArmstrong They could if it was clear to them that it's irrelevant. But if they're confused by the question then they wouldn't be sure that any edit they make isn't in conflict with the author's intent because they don't understand the author's intent.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that something is impossible is a legitimate answer.

If something has no answer, it [should be closed](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/).

Answer (score 1):

First, to answer your main question:

> What should I do with legitimate questions that can't be answered? ... The answer is just plain "you can't"

Questions in the form "Is this possible?" and asking for such answer are on-topic on Stack Overflow. So, nothing to do at such a question from your side in general (except of course maybe voting - depends on your choice).

"*You can't do X.*" is also fine answer, even if it might not seem for you as such at the first place. It gives an answer to the provided question, that X isn't possible. Answerers also tend to add informative and relevant side information at such answers, which can be helpful to clear the context.

So in fact, such question *can* be answered.

But the problem is to detect whether the question can be really directly answered or not (the question is too unclear/unfocused). With that, let's get straight to the next paragraph.

---

Second, discussing the real problem here:

The problem in your case is the quality of the post itself and that you attempt to anyhow intermix the concern if said questions and answers are on-topic with the reasoning of the review suspension (even if not explicitly intended).

Getting to the specific question, the issue here is that the description of the problem (what didn't work) paired with the expected result is unclear.

Consider the sentence

> The problem is that when I create an iFrame, it works as expected but when using Chrome Dev Tools, I am able to know the Link in the iFrame.

OP said that it works with iFrame (? - the title says it does not work with iFrame), then gets Chrome Dev Tools involved in the game and he is be able to know the link then. The following question says again he isn't be able to achieve the desired effect with iFrame.

It is at least completely unclear to me what OP tried to do and what is he wanting to do with that information.

That's why "Looks OK" isn't appropriate in this case. The question should be edited to get a clear cut and make the problem more understanding. "Looks OK" would mean there is no problem with this question, which isn't the case.

"Unsalvageable" would be the appropriate option as the question can only be edited by the author into shape.

Links:

- [Adopt a consistent policy on what "Requires Editing" means in the review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332546/12139179)
- [Change triage guidelines for "requires editing"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321895/12139179)

Answer (score 0):

> So what should I do in these cases, where the question itself is a
> perfectly valid, clear question, but cannot be answered?

Whether a question is clear and salvageable or not is pretty subjective. For someone who is an expert in that subject it can seem salvageable but for someone else it may not. Use your best judgement in this scenarios. If you are not sure just skip the question and move on with the next one.

A negative answer to a question is perfectly fine with a bit of an explanation as to why it's not possible and can be helpful to future viewers.Sometimes questions lack context of the actual business problem which OP is trying to solve and directly state OP's approach and the problem they are facing while working through that approach.In these scenarios knowing that OPs approach is not feasible, it's hard to provide an alternative feasible solution and some folks may be inclined towards closing the question as "Needs details or clarity".

Answer (score -3):

The problem is your presumption that the linked question is legitimate one.

It is, **but not for Stack Overflow.**

The question is extremely vague, showing no research effort or attempt at solving the problem by the asker. It also lacks justification for **why** the asker is trying to do what they're asking, which is vital to determine whether a question is an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189401).

But most importantly, the question is predicated on a fundamental lack of understanding of the problem space in which it's being asked. Nobody who knows an iota about IFrames and URLs and HTTP will ever think to ask this question, because it literally doesn't make sense to do so.

Therefore, the correct answer to this question isn't "no", it's "no, and why would you ever ask that?" - neither of which are a good fit for the type of answer we want on Stack Overflow.

Finally, since the answer is "no", any other answer to this question is almost certainly going to be either flat out wrong, very low quality, or plain spam.

In short, in its current state it's a terrible question that can only attract terrible answers. It cannot be salvaged except by the asker, and as we've already established, they don't know enough to salvage it. Hence, it is the very opposite of OK: it is unsalvageable, and your suspension was correct.

For this sort of question, also **do not waste your time** attempting to prove to the asker why the answer is "it's not possible" [as is recommended here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261184/70345). That question, and its answer, were written in 2014 when askers actually cared to learn. Nowadays, they just want a solution that makes the impossible possible - attempting to explain to them why it's not will only upset them.

Comment: This is quite ignorant of the value such a question still provides. Even if it is impossible, it is good to answer the question that way. Not every who asks question has studied the field beforehand. So people do ask stupid questions. However, if more people ask themselves this seemingly stupid question, they might find that very question, which in fact will answer their question.