# I don't understand how to get more information about a review queue suspension and actually learn from it

Tags: support, review-suspension

I got suspended for saying Looks Ok on this post https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27430952

I just read it over again and agree with my take and one other person agreed. Two people just stated that it Required Editing. So 4 out of 5 people thought the question content was okay.

What additional clarity does someone think is needed? The person wanted 10 divs and was looking for some sort of syntax that would make it quick and easy. Couldn't be clearer.

I've read other questions about suspensions and the answers state that a suspension only happens if there's a history of bad reviews. Well, okay, but I certainly haven't received any feedback about a history of bad reviews.

And I'm now suspended until Nov 6. That seems pretty harsh and I haven't learned anything from this suspension. It just seems like a difference of opinion.

A few weeks ago I was suspended for using Requires Editing incorrectly. So I did learn something from that one. But because the penalty is so harsh I rarely click that button even if editing is required.

It seems penalties should be less steep and/or a better feedback mechanism should be in place if someone is making too many mistakes.

All this is going to do is cause me to Skip 20%-30% more questions and decrease my ability to acutally help triage rather than make me a better reviewer.

UPDATE: It looks like someone reversed the decision. For now I appear to have access to the review queues again. Thanks to whomever that was.

Comment: The question does not look entirely clear to me. Maybe OP's referring to putting 10 such elements next to each other in the DOM, but I'm not completely sure, and it seems he hasn't come back to clarify anything since asking yesterday, so I'd probably have VTC'd. But you're right that it still *just seems like a difference of opinion*, others like you might interpret it differently.

Comment: At the very least it requires some editing (spaces before punctuation could be removed, in English we use a colon alone, not with a hyphen following; the formatting of the HTML could be improved, "but it doesn't worked" is not grammatically correct)...

Comment: What was unclear about the question in the comments from one of the close voters?

Comment: It looks like someone reversed the decision, so thanks to whomever did that. I have access to the queues again.

Comment: This is my understanding of how it really works with reviews: The trick is not to apply your own judgement on a post when you review. The trick is to apply the judgement of others and knowing when a post will get closed and when it will be allowed to stay open. When you misjudge that, you're likely to get suspended. The rules set out in the help center are not to be interpreted as rules, but merely guidelines and anyone can close any post if their opinion is that it should be closed.. basically in time, you'll be able to predict the future :)

Comment: Thanks @Scratte It's just frustrating that on a Q&A site there's no way to Q&A about things like this. I get it. People are busy they don't want to have to explain to every single person who got suspended why they got suspended. And they don't want to see the same "Why did I get suspended?" questions over and over again. But as I've observed from myself and others in meta: it's really frustrating when it happens to you and you have no one to discuss it with, apparently. I thank the commenters and Alexei for taking the time to help me because it really did help.

Comment: Perhaps they need to make the "Are you paying attention?" tests a little more subtle with feedback to help you. 90% of the time its an obvious spam. 10% of the time its a question from someone with 200k reputation and 20 gold badges and obviously it Looks OK. If we picked some questions in the middle people could maybe learn from the "are you paying attention" tests. Maybe instead of just "are you paying attention" there should be "do you really know the rules?" tests.

Comment: Perhaps before gaining access to triage queues, there should be a trial period. Or a series of test questions you need to get right. Say 100? I think that'd be a pretty good sample size to see if you get the rules. And I think it's be a more useful learning tool than a 2 week suspension.

Comment: They are very fine ideas, but they work from a premise that there really are rules that apply for all cases. There isn't. It only appears as though there are these rules. That's what I'm trying to tell you. A Question that I find perfectly clear can be unclear to another user. If that other user happens to be able to suspend me, I'll get suspended for not raising a flag on the post.. I've managed to get through 3000 reviews with only 2 suspensions merely because I learned to not just read the posts, but to have an idea of where the post was headed even if I strongly disagreed with it.

Comment: I've applied Skip in such cases (unless I was willing to really make a point), and I think I've Skipped 9 out of 10 posts. In short: It's not about reviewing, it's about applying someone else's opinion on whether the post should be closed.

Comment: I'd argue that, regarding Scratte's advice, even if it kinda *does* work that way, I don't believe it *should* work that way. It should be *much* more clear and better defined. Obviously not every post will fall neatly into a single review category, but we're clearly in need of improvements. Also wanted to drop a link to the [review queue improvement project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346901/776523) that's in the works to overhaul the entire experience.

Comment: Thanks @zcoop98 that initiative is great to see. It's nice to see them capturing many of the problems including the one that hit me: "Inappropriate actions on review tasks or audits can lead to a suspension of privileges with no obvious means of understanding what happened."

Comment: To highlight @Scratte point - that site rules are one thing and voting (which should align to the rules) is different - my answer here is upvoted (and no downvotes/comments so far) despite making a claim about "not possible" answers that is essentially opposite of the site rules/guidance - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer. If that is the case for particular question and you get suspended for it bringing particular question to meta to explain why the particular rule was not applied could help with changing the rule or voting outcome.

Comment: While the overhaul of the review system seems promising, I do not hold high hopes for it. The problem here is **not** the user interface. For new reviewers that gets suspended because they do not understand the buttons, sure.. But that's all it will do. No overhaul of the user interface is going to change that reviewers need to know the opinion of other users, especially the opinion of the moderator that decided to suspend them. I wrote an Answer about all my confusion once: [Upcoming Feature: New Question Close Experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394890)

Comment: @SecretAgentMan It is. But Skipping 27000 posts to review 3000 is just not very good use of anyone's time, is it?

Comment: I’m skipping even more today than yesterday

Comment: @MichaelWelch That is only a natural result of being suspended. I'm a stubborn kind of person and after I started on a queue, I stayed with it until I got the shiny badge. Now.. I wonder why I did it. It's of no value to me really and I feel my time would have been much better spent on something else. I think I spent on average 10-15 minutes on every post I reviewed, and most of that time trying to see the future. The past month a moderator have been closing some 1000 posts a day, so Stack clearly doesn't need me to help out with this.

Comment: @Scratte I hear ya. I've been working on this badge for years. In fits and spurts. I go for a week or two and then forget about it. Then I happen upon SO a few months later for something and think "Where am I at?" Let's try to get a few more points. I typically pick up a little bit of reputation at the same time as I end up finding a question or two I want to answer.

Comment: @Scratte I disagree that the overhaul won't help, but I understand where you're coming from. I also speak as someone who reviews not that often, and avoids Triage queue altogether because the experience seems so shoddy and inconsistent, with posts about bad audits and inconsistent suspensions seemingly being posted every other day.

Comment: Ok, I just now discovered SOCVR. I was hoping such a thing existed. I've learned from the close votes on this post that THIS is not the right place for questions of the type I asked. And I did post one other question in meta helping me judge a review I was doing. I quickly deleted it when I sensed it just wasn't the correct place. So I assume SOCVR is a good place to get some help?

Comment: These are the posts that helped me most: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/), [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/) and [How does the Triage queue work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650/) and all the pages in the help center about [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)..
and [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).. Of course, it doesn't stop there. I read another million posts about the "Not an Answer" and the "Very Low Quality" flags too.

Comment: would be great when you are granted a privilege some of this was "given to you". Perhaps it was. I've had some of these privileges for 5 years but didn't exercise them that frequently and probably don't recall what info was given. Certainly at the time I had no idea I would need to do so much homework. I only today discovered how to see my flag history. Been studying my user page a lot and never could find it. Didn't think it existed until I saw a help article mention flag history page.

Comment: Perhaps some of those posts were "given" to me, but by users, not by Stack or the system. Most of them I searched for and a lot of them were duplicates or linked to from another post. It's a maze to figure out which to read and which to skip, so I didn't skip any. I spend the better part of two months on meta just to get acquainted with the inner workings on the site. Hanging out in SOCVR is certainly not a bad place for discussions about curating the site. You can even just sit quietly and see the post that come through there and pick up on "how to predict the future" ;)

Comment: I was so confused when you said earlier in the comments that you "could see where things were headed even if you didn't agree". I was like where is he looking at this information?

Comment: That was from mostly the queues, but of course also from the chat room :) I have a modified version of this user script that will tell me if a post has [close votes](https://stackapps.com/questions/8671/view-close-and-delete-votes-with-low-reputation), and I check to see what others users have picked on a post in review too. And I've learned to get a feeling of it, which comes after a couple of thousand reviews ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the question is correctly closed as not (yet) answerable, so voting other than "unsalvageble" is a mistake. Whether you/all reviewer on that post should be suspended or not is a moderator's call. Note that post was closed by moderator's vote - so it is very likely they gave suspensions at the same time.

Your "looks ok" vote on that post does not look justifiable to me at all - post definitely would benefit from community editing to make it aligned with English grammar. "Requires editing" would be right choice as you believe the question is indeed answerable.

Why I don't see it answerable - "not possible" without any alternatives is generally frowned upon and OP did not provide any way out to suggest alternatives and guessing what they can use. Picking one of many plausible alternatives from CSS, XSLT, hundreds of programming languages starting with JavaScript, thousands of frameworks does not sound like a good choice for an non-opinionated answer.

I can see alternative view point (and it is official policy of the site - [Is "this is not possible" an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer)) - indeed writing an answer that explains that HTML in itself does not support any looping of HTML-generation constructs and thus one have to use some other languages/tools to generate repetitive HTML. Also I'm afraid it could be seen as less helpful than closing/asking OP to explain what options are available.

Comment: Thanks @Alexei. This gives me a little more to go on.

Comment: Your comment that the only answer to this is "not possible" is not very useful to others is helpful.