# How best to edit questions for which the answer turns out to be "not possible...but"

Tags: discussion

I sometimes ask questions for which the answer is ["this is not possible"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer).  One common source of these (and I suspect this happens to other question askers as well) is the relative lack of power of certain tools, such as CSS or regex.  CSS can accomplish a lot of things, but it can't accomplish everything.  So, questions asking "How can I accomplish X using CSS" sometimes have a "not possible" answer.

However, things that aren't possible in CSS are usually possible with JavaScript.  This tends to elicit answers that "this isn't possible in CSS, but it *can* be accomplished in JavaScript. See here:...". [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71993071/how-can-i-scale-all-images-to-the-same-dimensional-area/72003152#72003152) (Note that in this question, @isherwood seems to have made a post hoc edit to the question to attempt to make the question accommodate his answer of "not possible... but".  IMHO making the question more vague doesn't help clarify though - it hides the aspect of "trying to accomplish this in CSS" which obviates the useful "not possible" answer.)

I now have a question about CSS with a JavaScript answer.  It seems that this answer actually answers *two* questions:

1. "Q: How to do this in CSS, A: Not possible" and
2. "Q: How to do this in JS, A: here's how...".

However, I can't edit my post so that it actually asks both of those questions; posts asking multiple questions get closed as **Needs More Focus**.

Does anyone have recommendations on general strategies to edit such questions post hoc or to a priori phrase questions that I suspect might be "not possible...but" so that they can accommodate both the original answer ("not possible", which is useful info to anyone looking to accomplish this) and *also* the new answer (the workaround) to the question I didn't ask?

Comment: *".. seems to have made a post-hoc edit to the question to attempt to make the question accommodate his answer .."* ... I honestly don't see how they did that. Do you mean by removing the "css" in the title? Tags don't belong into the title and they didn't add a "javascript" tag, so it is still only tagged with "css".

Comment: Just because someone provides additional information in their answer does not mean the question is magically asking multiple separate things. If the question is "how to do this in CSS" that's just one question. Someone can answer "you can't", and someone else can answer "you can't. Here is how you would do it in JS though" and both would be valid answers. If someone only said "Here is how you would do it in JS", that's a problematic answer, but it still doesn't mean the question has a problem.

Comment: @TylerH "has a problem" At the same time, a visitor to the site who reads this question would not expect to find an answer detailing how to accomplish the workaround.  My goal here is to improve the documentation to be better, not necessarily to simply meet the bare guidelines for site acceptability.

Comment: An edit isn’t necessary: it’s always OK for an answer to include alternatives and work arounds. This is true even when something is possible in the given language/tech. For example, one could ask how to do something in JavaScript and an answer saying “This is possible using just CSS, here’s the code…” would be OK.

Comment: @BSMP "would be OK" but now there is "hidden" info in an answer.  When I read a question about how to do something in CSS, I wouldn't necessarily expect to find a js answer.  Again, the goal here isn't to make a black-and-white distinction between what's okay or not okay, but to improve my question so that people searching for answers have the maximum probability of finding them.  IMHO, my question should lead people to "expect" the answers that they find there.

Comment: @Tom it seems that questions asking for solutions in css [frequently reference css in the question title](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+css)?  Is this inappropriate?

Comment: "a visitor to the site who reads this question *would not expect to find ...the workaround*" - why? My guess that most visitors are looking for *any* solution - those who already investigated the problem likely know "no" answer and need a workaround, and those who did not research are likely don't care about exact language match either...

Comment: @Him When you build an actual sentence where the tag is mentioned, then it _can_ be fine, but it is still redundant. In this case, however, it was just a prefix to the actual question text.

Comment: @Him When I ask a question here, I have no control over what someone decides to include in an answer to that question. I can leave comments or vote on it, but if someone wants to provide additional information beyond what I asked, that information becomes an aspect of the answer, not an aspect of the question, and attempting to penalize the question for it somehow is incorrect. Doing so would discourage many of the more useful/educational answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Him Stack Overflow is not a documentation resource; it is a Q&A repository. In fact, the organization tried to leverage its position and skill set to create "SO Documentation" specifically to serve that role, but that attempt failed and was shuttered shortly after launch. I recommend not trying to make questions and answers fit neatly into a 'documentation' format, because that's not what the site is designed to provide.

Comment: @TylerH what do you mean by "penalize"?  I don't view editing my questions with the intent to improve site content as a "penalty".  When I ask a question, it is because I don't know what the answer is.  Sometimes, in retrospect and in the knowledge of what the answers are, it turns out that my question could have been better.  Making after-the-fact changes to my question to improve the overall content seems like correct action to me.

Comment: @Him You suggested earlier that a question should be closed as "Needs Focus" if someone posts an answer to it that shows how to do something other than what the question asked. That seems like penalizing (read: "applying a penalty to") the question to me.

Comment: @TylerH "**Needs more Focus**" is a stock close-vote reason.  It's not my opinion.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I am aware of the close reason's existence. What is your opinion is whether that close reason applies to the question. By the logic in your opinion, we can flag any _question_ as "spam" if someone posts a spam _answer_ to it. I hope that makes it more clear how faulty your logic is.

Comment: @TylerH I'm still not sure what you're getting at.  Perhaps you're misunderstanding my question.  I'm not asking about how to deal with *answering* questions that have a "not possible.... but" type solution.  I'm asking about how to phrase my *question*.

Comment: @Him I am responding directly to this part of your question above "*I now have a question about CSS with a JavaScript answer. It seems that this answer actually answers two questions. 1) "Q: How to do this in CSS, A: Not possible" and 2) "Q: How to do this in js, A: here's how...". However, questions are not allowed to ask two questions, they Need More Focus.*" If it is unclear to you how this is relevant then perhaps you should remove that paragraph from your question.

Comment: @TylerH that paragraph specifically references aspects of the question.  If I create a question (in the SO sense) that asks two questions (in the Webster's sense) then my question (in the SO sense) "Needs More Focus".  In any case, I'm not feeling as though this conversation is productive.  If you'd like to edit my post to remove something that you don't like, feel empowered to do so.  Cheers.

Comment: You mentioned regex.  I always find mentioning [Tony the Pony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2487517) helps.

Comment: I think the problem TylerH was having is that you don't actually say that you want to ask both questions in your post. Your question went straight from "the answer addresses two questions" to "the question needs more focus". I've edited your question here to clarify that you're talking about a hypothetical edit making your question off topic, not the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A car with square wheels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels)

Comment: @gnat not quite, as I really *do* want a CSS solution to the problem.  That would be ideal.  The fact that it doesn't exist doesn't make me not want it.  I still want it.  It's more like a car that gets 1000mpg.  Well, you can't have that, but here's the next best thing.

Comment: Seems pretty simple; Ask the question. Say what you've said here: "I'd prefer a pure CSS solution. If this is not possible, a solution using JavaScript (preferably not using any libraries) is acceptable." I added the bit about libraries, to fend off the inevitable 1001 "there's a jQuery plugin that does that" answers. Nothing exciting, just a few words about requirements.

Answer (score 6):

Are you aware of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

If you know that there are other technologies which might solve the problem, it would be useful to either say you'd accept answers using them *or* give a brief reason why you can't use them (but don't be upset if people don't accept the reason).

Also, remember that the Stack Exchange sites are intended to be a repository of knowledge for everyone, so someone else with the same problem may be happy to find an answer which uses, say, jQuery, even if that particular answer was of no use to you. (The "[Wisdom of the Ancients](https://xkcd.com/979/)" XKCD cartoon is so nearly applicable here.)

Comment: I'm not sure that this is an XY problem.  I *really do want to accomplish this with CSS*.  That is my question.  The fact that it is "not possible" doesn't mean that I was asking a question about something else.  In all seriousness, if the question were "how to do this in Javascript?" I wouldn't have even asked the question, because I could have done it myself.

Comment: The XY problem is not about using a different language than what is ideal. It's about trying to force a square peg in a round hole because you found a square peg first and stopped looking for the round peg.

Comment: Except the square peg may have benefits over the round peg, such as being cheaper or whatever. So if there _is_ a way to fit it, it would be preferrable. Only if it's not possible, one would consider using the round peg as solution then. (CSS is usually preferrable over JS because of its higher performance and declarative nature.)

Comment: @TylerH which fits this scenario to a T. "I want smooth scrolling for this section with JS, how to do that?" "You don't need JS, you just need CSS!". Remove "with JS" and the answer becomes "This is how you do it with CSS".

Comment: @CherryDT Yes, if you change the scenario, then the label may not apply anymore.

Comment: Let's also not rush to posting an answer.  In 2022, it is VERY, VERY hard (nearly impossible) to ask a good, unique, narrow, on-topic question.  If the question has been Resolved Elsewhere, please flag/vote to close instead of adding more redundant noise to Stack Overflow.  It is entirely likely that Stack Overflow already has 3 or 5 or more pre-existing pages that provide the necessary solution. [... help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental,place.)

Answer (score 1):

As with many things in life: **it is a judgement call.**

When deciding whether to widen the scope of a question based on answers, always ask yourself if value will be lost were the answer to be removed? Some answers, even if they broaden the scope of the question are stellar: detailed, properly formatted, well-written, etc. They provide value, so it makes sense to tweak the question a little to make an allowance for it (that said, if the question *explicitly* states that solutions in other technologies are *unacceptable,* I would avoid making such an edit as we generally strive to [preserve authorial intent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303220/11407695)).

If answer does not provide great value, try to find a common duplicate target that explains how to solve the problem in the technology of the answer, and if so, then the answer is actually *harming* the repository of knowledge such as we are because every user landing on it is one user that seen the canonical *less.* I do not propose outright *deletion* of such answers, but they certainly do not merit widening the scope of the question.

---

An off-note about your example post: it seems that you misunderstood the nature of the edit — the user was simply [removing tag duplication from title](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) as the question is already tagged [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) (the original title started with "css how").